# Custom FormBuilder

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, erb

I'm starting Rails and Ruby for a short time. But I try to make it the cleanest way I can. So, in an attempt to clean my view, I try to custom my `FormBuilder`:

```
# /config/initializers/custom_form_builder.rb    
class ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder

  # My test form function
  def test label
    return "Whatever I want to do ..."
  end
end
```

And then I can use it like this:

```
# /app/views/test/test.html.erb
...
<%= form_for test, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.test(":-)") %>
  ...
<% end %>
...
```

This part works perfectly fine. However, what I want to do know is how to create form views containing the HTML code that I want to use in my forms.  This way, I can store the HTML of all my form in a pseudo-HTML way, and structured within my directories.

So, I've created a template:

```
# /app/views/forms/test.html.erb
<input type="text" value="test" />
```

And I've tried to render it from my `FormBuilder`:

```
# /config/initializers/custom_form_builder.rb
def test label
  render "forms/test"
end
```

And I added it to my routes:

```
# /config/routes.rb
match "/forms/test"    => "forms#test"
```

My questions:

1. Do I try to make it work the wrong way?
2. Is it possible to render from my `FormBuilder` class?
3. Is there some useless code in there?

Answer (score 1):

I made it a different way. But, the answer was quite simple.

The class ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder inherit of the @template attribute.

And to render my partials, I just need to call it this way :

```
def test label
  @template.render "/forms/test"
end
```

Then you can use the partial as specified on [RoR Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials)